How does table partitioning size affect query performance?
In my system, I have a set of Oracle 19c database tables which stored temparary data, which are getting expired. I have a solution where I partitioned these tables with the create timestamp of these entries.
CREATE TABLE TEMP (
            ID VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
            TYPE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
            CONTEXT_OBJECT BLOB,
            TIME_CREATED NUMBER(19)
)partition by range (TIME_CREATED) INTERVAL(<some value>)

In this I have tested that setting the INTERVAL to for a value equivalent to a one day.
In this scenarios, partition size is growing about 300 GB during the day.
I can see that initial insert queries are file but with the DB load INSERT INTO VALUES (...) ... queries getting sometimes 10 seconds to complete.
So I wanted to try reducing the interval to may be 1 hour instead of a day and check if it improves performance of the insert queries. As per the analysis the root cause for the insert query to get slow is due to DW – contention.
FYI The index for this table is global indexes. One column also contains a BLOB object too.
The reason for partitioning is to drop partitions based on their TIME_CREATED once a expirey time exceeds.
Can someone help me figure this out?

The size of the partition should not affect the performance of the INSERTs. As your index is global, you could have some contention there if there are a lot of INSERTs going on in several partitions.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I agree with @DiegoFerruchelli, the table/partition size will not have an impact on the insert operation. When you see "DW – contention" contention then you can try to find out what this means and look for countermeasures. A quick look at Oracle's support portal shows "Wait Event - enq: DW - contention (Doc ID 1331665.1)", with the information:

WaitEvent-enq:DW-contention(DocID1331665.1)
Goal
This Note describes the Enqueue "enq: DW - contention" which is related to SecureFile LOBS and acquiring the In-Memory Dispenser Latch.
Solution
The DW enqueue wait event is related to SecureFile LOBs and acquiring the In-Memory Dispenser Latch.
In-Memory Dispenser - Free space allocations to SecureFile objects are managed in-memory through a shared-memory data structure (part of SGA) known as the In-Memory Space Dispenser.
References
NOTE:743773.1-SMCO (SpaceManagementCoordinator)ForAutoextend On Datafiles And How To Disable/Enable

This is not much information

Actually, it's very good information. If @LLS is using secure LOB files and the in-memory functionality, he may enlarge the related DB parameters. If he's not, and also according to the note, I would check the storage parameters for the segments (partitions and indexes next extent), tablespace and temporary files. They may be too small.

Global indexes are bad when you truncate/drop expired data, because the entire index needs to be rebuild. Better create local indexes, then you can drop/truncate outdated partitions which is very fast. I guess the insert are not slow because of the insert commands itself. They might be slow, because the database is busy with removing expired data.

DiegoFerruchelli and Wernfried Domscheit miracle173 thanks for the provided hints. I will try with local indexes instead of global. In my drop index query I have written it as ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME DROP PARTITION PARTITION_NAME UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
COMMIT;
I will remove the UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES and check. Also I am dropping these partitions in 1 hour frequency.
Sorry if lack of ino :(

GLOBAL indexes aren't bad per se. But @WernfriedDomscheit Is right. For an escenario like yours, they may be killers. I would also enlarge the interval and I would space the dropping of the partitions. You don't need to create and drop them in pairs and all the time. You may (pre)create several partitions together and drop several by night, when the INSERTs are not running.

Also, If your data is disposable (and no other session is reading it), wouldn't it be better to use a (non-partitioned) temporary table with ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS? You're using one INSERT per record (which is already a bad practice), but how many concurrent sessions? And what about the COMMITs?

Also check https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/asynchronous-global-index-maintenance-for-drop-and-truncate-partition-12cr1 (and the linked documentation).
